# Replacing a value with NULL in a table in SQL Server using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

My table will contain the following values. **h1,h2,h3** are varchar fields with size 1

```
    **Register  Date        Year    Batch   h1      h2      h3**    
    1138M0321   02-08-2013  3       1       A       A       NULL
    1138M0323   02-08-2013  3       1       P       P       NULL
    1138M0324   02-08-2013  3       1       P       P       NULL    
    1138M0325   02-08-2013  3       1       P       P       NULL
```

I need to **update** one of these fields**(h1/h2/h3)** with NULL. But I can only add **""** and not actually **NULL** 
How can I update the table with NULL?

Comment: Why can you only add ""? What is the rule, which rows and fields do you want to set to NULL?

Comment: depending on the condition I need to update H1 or H2 or H3. I can't make the value back to NULL which is the field's starting state when it doesn't hold any value

Comment: Depending on _which_ condition, how should we show you the correct sql if we don't know the rule? What role plays the date field? Why can't you set the value back(?) to NULL? What have you tried, what was the result, what is the desired result?

Comment: Here is the rule.. WHERE year=" & year & " AND batch=" & batch & "" AND date= '02-08-2013'    I tried DBNull.Value but still it doesn't place NULL

Comment: Please show the code that you're trying to use.

Comment: query = "UPDATE student_attendance_table SET h1 = " & System.DBNull.Value & " WHERE year=3 AND batch=1 AND date= '02-08-2013'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NULL` value must be SQL, not a .NET value, so instead of trying things like:

```
"... SET h1 = " & NULL & " ... "
```

Simply use this in the query:

```
"... SET h1 = NULL ... "
```

Note that:

> Null values cannot be used for information that is required to distinguish one row in a table from another row in a table, such as primary keys.

See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Why use VB Nulls at all ...

```
UPDATE student_attendance_table SET h1 = NULL WHERE...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE student_attendance_table SET h3 = 'NULL' WHERE...
```

This will make your table look like this:

```
**Register  Date        Year    Batch   h1      h2      h3**    
    1138M0321   02-08-2013  3       1       A       A       'NULL'
    1138M0323   02-08-2013  3       1       P       P       'NULL'
    1138M0324   02-08-2013  3       1       P       P       'NULL'
    1138M0325   02-08-2013  3       1       P       P       'NULL'
```

And when you want to display the values of column h3. You can `trim` the single quotes and display NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a NOT NULL constraint

"UPDATE student_attendance_table SET h1 = " & System.DBNull.Value & " WHERE...

Comment: How can I do this in vb.net there is no NULL when I try like this "UPDATE student_attendance_table SET h1 = " & NULL & " WHERE... there is only Nullable and DBNull If I use DBNull it's showing error

Comment: Can't you use System.DBNull.Value?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to stick to using NULL then it must be included within statement itself without any parameter, use like the classical way:

```
"UPDATE student_attendance_table SET h1 = NULL WHERE...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Update Table Set Column = (NULL As Column Type) where Condition"
```